# Using pseudo element to add asterisk to input element using the required attribute

Tags: css

I want to add an asterisk to the input element that has a required attribute. and to be inside the input.

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" class="text-input" required>

[required] {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

[required]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: red;
  content: " *";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;  
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PxgD8/)

I don't want to add more elements or classes, is that possible.

---

It looks like that I can't do this this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, you can’t. The [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) says: “This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.” It has not been defined so far. And `input` is treated as a replaced element. Browsers generally do not support `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements on them. If they did, the generated content would be inserted at the end or at the start of the element’s content, which is empty by HTML specs, so it’s not clear at all what *could* happen.

Note that using an `input` element without an associated `label` element breaks basic usability and accessibility guidelines. In particular, the `placeholder` attribute is not meant to be used instead of a label.

Comment: Yes now I know why I can't do this, hope this will be done in the future. And thanks for the note, I have to reconsider this one instead

Answer (score 1):

Note that you cannot use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements on replaced elements such as form elements (inputs) and image elements.

You may want to wrap your input within a parent element and apply `:after` to this

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example for add an asterix, but just after the input

http://jsfiddle.net/erqrN/1/

```
<div class="required">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>

<style>
    .required:after { content:" *"; }
</style>​
```

You can't use `before` and `after` on input for that ;)

Edit : Like that :

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name *">
```

Comment: Sad to hear that i can't, i don't want to add more elements

Comment: Or you can use the attribut placeholder, and write manually the *